# boost::asio Coroutine TS: How join / select multiple coroutines?

Tags: join, boost, coroutine, asio

I'm study boost::asio Coroutine TS recently. but I dont know how to join 2 running coroutines. I googled but no results.

Comment: I even not able to make it compile :smile: How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a better solution. But I do have an ugly workaround...

Basically, I use a pair of piped fds to implement an async-event mechanism. So it only works on unix-like systems.

You may take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/icpz/open-snell/blob/b99334afb1/snell_server/src/async_utils/async_event.hh).

Usage:

```cpp
asio::io_context ctx;

AsyncEvent event{ctx.get_executor()};
event.Reset();

asio::co_spawn(ctx.get_executor(), /* coroutine that calls `co_await event.AsyncSet();' */, asio::detached);

co_await event.AsyncWait();
```

There's also a latch in the same directory.